# I need to find all unknown events X so that AX = AB

Tags: probability

I just started to study probability theory and faced with an exercise that I don't even imagine how to solve. Please, help!

Let A and B - events. Find all events X, so that AX = AB.
AX means that both events A and X are implemented at the same time.

PS. Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less a set theory question. Revised statement:

> Let $A,B \in E$ (event space). Find all $X\in E$ such that $A\cap X=A\cap B$.

As an intuitive approach notice $X=B$ first satisfies this. If we throw in any element (simple event) $x\in A^c$ notice $A\cap (B\cup \{x\})= (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap \{x\}) = A\cap B$.

Therefore it seems plausible that $X = B\cup C$ where $C\subseteq A^c$ represents all such $X$. But we can also include any events in $A\cap B$ (added this sentence).

As Henry noted, I missed some. It should be  $X\subseteq A^c \cup (A\cap B)$. See Henry's equivalent/shorter expression below.

Note: "Taking the complement" here is with respect to the sample space.

Comment: seem this is true, thank you

Comment: I would have thought $X=A \cap B$ was the smallest set satisfying $A\cap X=A\cap B$, so your solution should be $X=(A\cap B) \cup C$.  Take for example $E= \{1,2,3,4\}, A= \{1,2\}, B= \{1,3\}$ and $X= \{1,4\}$ which cannot be written as $B \cup C$